# Quickblox sending push notifications to development devices, but not to production devices on iOS

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, quickblox

I've been working on an app for a while that uses push notifications from the chat module of QuickBlox.

I've been testing the push notifications on my iPad and it works fine (Developer Device). I've added both of the certificates to QuickBlox and both are active(Developer & Production).

The production devices are being registered for remote notifications and they are showing that they registered for **production** push notifications. When I send a message to a developer device it receives the notification and it works fine, however when I send to a production device its not received.

If I try to send a push notification to production users from the admin panel it gets sent, but non receive it. The production users are internal and external testers in TestFlight. I heard the TestFlight testers have to use a production certificate so thats why I'm registering them as so. When I archive the build going to the store I make sure that I do it using the production provisioning profile. I don't know what else to do :O

Thanks in advance

edit: I tried using push notification tester for the certificate and it worked fine. It pushed and the push notification was received to the production device. Still not working on QuickBlox

Answer (score 0):

I tried to remove the certificate and then add it again, but that didn't help. I had to revoke my certificate then create a new one. After I added it, it took a good few hours until the notifications started to work. Must have been an issue with QuickBlox.

Comment: Do you still have this issue?

Comment: No I don't. revoking the certificate then creating a new one solved the issue. It takes a bit of time for Apple to revoke your certificate so lookout for that.